# Issue with sine wave in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, trigonometry

I'd be willing to bet the issue is with my math, rather than my JavaScript but...

I'm trying to create a sine wave that has an amplitude (total height) of the height of the container (in this case: 400px) and have the total length of the wavelength equal the width on the container (in this case: 600px).

In plain English: I'm trying to get #theSun to rise on the left side of the container, arc at 50% left, then fall until it sets at 100% left.

Can anyone lend me their eyes and spot what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a working example of the code/what's going wrong with it: http://jsfiddle.net/fasterhorses/vbkPb/

```
// HTML
<div id="container">
 <div id="theSun"></div>
</div>​

// CSS
#container {
  border: 1px solid #f00;        
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;    
}

#theSun {
  background: yellow;            
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;   
}

// JavaScript (w/ jQuery 1.7)

var sun = $('#theSun');
var context = $('#container');
var contextHeight = context.height();
var contextWidth = context.width();


// Move sun to horizon line
sun.css({"top": contextHeight});

var a = contextHeight / 2;
var b = (Math.PI / contextWidth) * 2;

for (var i = 0; i <= contextWidth; i++) {
  var arc = a * Math.sin(b * i);
  if (i >= (contextWidth / 2)) {
    sun.animate({
      left: '+=' + i,
      top: '+=' + arc
    }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
  } else {
    sun.animate({
      left: '+=' + i,
      top: '-=' + arc
    }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
  } 
}
```

​

Comment: You've got the code set up to *add* the "i" and "arc" values on each animation segment, but "i" is the absolute horizontal position and you're computing "arc" as the absolute height ...

Comment: same for the left +=, without the +='s you get this http://jsfiddle.net/vbkPb/67/, a single sine wave (also added 1/2 context height to top, you should be able to take it from here

Comment: Also, a complete sin wave will have the sun going up and then down and then back up :-) [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/vbkPb/68/) is an update to your fiddle to show that.

Comment: I'm glad there are people smarter than me on here. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to this, but with the help and use of a jquery "path" plugin which has an example of animation along a sine wave path that you might find helpful to reference. (Or just use the plugin!)

Find more info here : http://boodigital.com/post/1984711395/bezier-curves-in-jquery   and here : https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path

We ended up tweaking our amplitude, frequency, and phase shift to achieve the perfect result. Hope this is of some help to you!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but it's a lot closer to what you need:

```
var sun = $('#theSun');
var context = $('#container');
var contextHeight = context.height();
var contextWidth = context.width();


// Move sun to horizon line
sun.css({"top": contextHeight});

for (var x = 0; x <= contextWidth; x++) {
    var angle = Math.acos((x - (contextWidth / 2)) / (contextWidth / 2));
    var y = contextHeight - Math.sin(angle) * contextHeight;
    sun.animate({
      left: x,
      top: y
    }, 5);
    // Animation complete.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example here http://jsfiddle.net/vbkPb/70/

```
var sun = $('#theSun');
var context = $('#container');
var contextHeight = context.height();
var contextWidth = context.width();


// Move sun to horizon line
sun.css({
    "top": contextHeight
});

var a = contextHeight;
var b = Math.PI / contextWidth;
var i = 0;

function moveSun() {
    if (i < contextWidth) {
        var arc = a * Math.sin(i * b);
        var left = i / contextWidth;
        sun.animate({
            left: i,
            top: contextHeight - arc
        }, 25, 'linear');
        i++;
        moveSun().delay(500);
    }
}

moveSun();
```